# Android Sensor Manager delay: setting it to a custom value

Tags: android, accelerometer

I would like to customize the delay time used here. If SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL is used then the delay is about .2 seconds (200,000 microseconds). I would like the delay to be around .35 seconds. The delay doesn't have to be exact, just greater than .2 seconds and less than .4. Any suggestions how I would go about that? Min API is 15.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: you cannot choose the delay freely. The SensorManager is restricted to the default delays. You could use a lower delay and drop most of the data points, but that would be battery ineffcient. And the most important question is: why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: The reason is that I'm sending accelerometer data to an arduino based robot, and sometimes the data freezes. I would like to test whether a longer delay would stop the app from freezing.

Comment: yeah, but why not use .4?

Comment: I would try .4. But it isn't one of the default delays either. The reason I suspect this is the cause for the freeze is that if I make the delay smaller (SENSOR_DELAY_UI) then my app freezes almost right away.

Comment: @DanielShields it possible to set your desired value api level 9 onwards, however, its a just a suggestion or indication to Android system and won't be guaranteed. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your desired delay freely beside these four default values, however, it is not guaranteed. 
Example call:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, 100);
# 100 microsecond is the desired delay between two events here.
# you can change it to whatever value suits you.
```

It only works API level 9 onwards according to Android documentation.

Details:

```
boolean registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, 
                Sensor sensor, 
                int samplingPeriodUs)
```

**samplingPeriodUs**

*int: The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST **or, the desired delay between events in microseconds. Specifying the delay in microseconds only works from Android 2.3 (API level 9) onwards. For earlier releases, you must use one of the SENSOR_DELAY_*** constants.*

You can read this for the details.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Comment: yes, I read all that too. That's the whole reason I'm asking the question to find a work-around.

Comment: There is no work around for it as you cannot force such an interval in Android.

Comment: Also you can choose a delay freely beside those four default values. It wont be gauranted though.

Comment: Yes, you get it!! That's what I'm asking! How do I choose a delay freely besides those four default values? I don't care if it is exact.

Comment: See my answer again, you will see how to do it. I updated it with an example. Just put the number of milliseconds you want to place. See the bold statements. You should read the docs with more attention :)

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks! I'll try it when I get home